# Дополнительные отступы в input text в Firefox

Tags: padding, text, firefox, css

Только в Firefox в `<input type="text">` появляются дополнительные отступы в 1 пиксель слева и сверху.

Как их убрать?

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/SN9vT/) http://jsfiddle.net/SN9vT/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/SN9vT/2/

```
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

чтобы во всех браузерах было одинаково, пропиши жесткую высоту для всех инпутов.

ах да, забыл. span-у с классом col1 дай display:block и float: left. И не забывайте использовать line-height.

И тогда все станет чётенько и ровненько =)

P.S. отступ какой? padding или margin? ибо с марджином решение я написал

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте **[здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/qa/15626/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Так:

```
.col1, .col2 {display:inline-block;}
```